# Delete all wrapper types in a nested type

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Is it possible to write a metafunction that, given a type with several occurrences of certain type `template<class> class Decor`, returns the type without the appearances of the class `Decorator`.

An example would be to convert following type
`A<Decor<T<B<A<Decor<C>>>>>>`
into
`A<T<B<A<C>>>>`

We assume that the structure of the final type is indeed a correct type, but we do not assume anything on the structure of the input type. It could be the case that some types used to construct the input type were of the form `template<class...> class` or any other type class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 template <class T>
 struct RemDec
 { using type = T; };
 template <class T>
 struct RemDec<Decor<T>>
 { using type = T; };
 template <class T>
 struct RemDec<T&>
 { using type = typename RemDec<T>::type&; };
 template <class T>
 struct RemDec<T&&>
 { using type = typename RemDec<T>::type&&; };
 template <class T>
 struct RemDec<const T>
 { using type = typename RemDec<T>::type const; };
 template <class T>
 struct RemDec<volatile T>
 { using type = typename RemDec<T>::type volatile; };
 template <template <typename...> class TT, class... Ts>
 struct RemDec<TT<Ts...>>
 { using type = TT<typename RemDec<Ts>::type...>; }
```

You will need even more specializations if your templates might have value- or template-template-arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class template and a couple of specializations like these:

```
template<typename T>
struct RemDec {
    using type = T;
};

template<template<typename...> class C, typename... T>
struct RemDec<C<T...>> {
    using type = C<typename RemDec<T>::type...>;
};

template<typename T>
struct RemDec<Decorator<T>> {
    using type = typename RemDec<T>::type;
};
```

The class template helps to stop iterating over your chain of types.
The first specialization *memorizes* a class template and helps cleaning up what remains.
The last specialization removes the `Decorator` detected and goes on analyzing what remains.

---

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename>
struct Decorator {};

template<typename...>
struct S {};

template<typename T>
struct RemDec {
    using type = T;
};

template<template<typename...> class C, typename... T>
struct RemDec<C<T...>> {
    using type = C<typename RemDec<T>::type...>;
};

template<typename T>
struct RemDec<Decorator<T>> {
    using type = typename RemDec<T>::type;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<
        typename RemDec<S<Decorator<S<S<Decorator<S<int>>>>>, Decorator<S<double>>>>::type,
        S<S<S<S<int>>>, S<double>>
    >::value, "!");
}
```

As you can see by running it, any *instance* of `Decorator` is removed from the original type.

Comment: God, you are right. I implemented almost this, but I missed something and I thought that you couldn't do this type of matching.

As I pointed out, the class could be variadic in its template argument, but the generalisation is trivial. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Lezkus Missed the variadic comment. Give me a few minutes to integrate the answer for that.

Comment: @Lezkus Done. Now the code is _variadic-oriented_. ;-)

Comment: @Deduplicator Well, I think OP got the idea. He will add all the other specializations required by the real problem. Likely...