# Delete wrappers of a nested type

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Continuation of the question:
[Delete all wrapper types in a nested type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697953/delete-all-wrapper-types-in-a-nested-type)

I realised that the solutions given to this question do not contemplate cases such that `std::array`, where one of the parameters is not a type but a value.

Is it possible to generalise those answers to cover these cases?

Comment: The solution is always more specializations ;-)

Comment: Absolutely, but what specialisations? I would like to make it generic, instead to having to hardcode an specialisation for the `std::array` type and for all the other types with template value parameters.

Comment: You cannot possibly get every type. You'd have to look for "array-like" containers that receive a type followed by a size_t